# Disappearing lighting when moving the camera around

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I have an issue in Unity where sometimes a mesh (or a few mesh) don't have proper lighting when viewed from far away, or turning the camera up close. I use mixed lighting on my spot and point lights. Does anyone know what can cause this?

https://streamable.com/er11a6

[image]

[image]

[image]